# jquery: iphone like animation?

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins

I have a front page that consists of a lot of small images like the iphone desktop, I want to animate like iphone(fly from the edge of page into the center of page).

Is there any existing plugins?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Are you finding this:

- [A Beautiful Apple-style Slideshow Gallery With CSS & jQuery](http://tutorialzine.com/2009/11/beautiful-apple-gallery-slideshow/)
- [Demo](http://demo.tutorialzine.com/2009/11/beautiful-apple-gallery-slideshow/demo.html)

There are many image gallery related jQuery plugins:

- [Awesome jQuery Sliders and Galleries](http://blancer.com/tutorials/77058/awesome-jquery-sliders-and-galleries/)