# JavaScript animation like iPhone application starting

Tags: javascript, jquery, iphone, core-animation, jquery-animate

iDevices (like: iPhone, iPad, iPod touch) has interesting animation. 
When any application starting - there are 2 animations step:
- disappearing all app icons from main screen
- and appearing executed app on screen

Does anybody saw this animation in browser? ? by JS, maybe some plugin (for jQuery?)?

Second part of animation almost clear how to make, but first animation it's not simple task, maybe is there any ready solution ?

Thanks.

P.S. and i don't want to apply it to any image gallery or something similar. It will be used in web-app

P.P.S. I'm looking the same what this guy want [jquery: iphone like animation?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4529710/jquery-iphone-like-animation), but he did not get any right answer :(

Comment: i could not see the animation.

Comment: jQuery isn't a plugin. And I don't think you want a plugin anyway, unless you think it reasonable to insist that all of your users install a plugin? (Hint: it's not reasonable.)

Comment: come on, guys. If you have an iPhone, for instance, run any application on it, and you will see how all icons from screen disappearing, and how your executed application appear.

When i mean plugin, means plugin for any framework - for example for jQuery.

Comment: My apologies, I misinterpreted the "plugin" thing. (Your edit makes that clear.) Seems not many of us have iPhones though - I certainly don't - but maybe the [jQuery explode](http://docs.jquery.com/UI/Effects/Explode) effect is closer to what you're looking for?

Comment: hm maybe you right! thanks a lot for this, i will look more on this effect. at least one part of this effect already founded. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

How do the items disappear? How do they reappear? In other words, what should the animations look like? You need to provide more details to get the best possible answers.

That said, in general this is trivial to do using jQuery:

```
$('.app').fadeOut(1000, function() {
  $('#newApp').fadeIn(1000);
});
```

Where .app are elements that need to be faded out, and #newApp is the app interface that will replace them.

Sample: http://jsfiddle.net/GregP/fg54C/

You can animate sizes as well (shrinking them and then making them invisible)... there are a bunch of things you could do.

Comment: this is what i'm talking about. The effect what I need it's not Fade in/out, it's another effect and what is it ? i don't know... If you never saw this on real device (like: iPhone, iPod touch, iPad) then it will be hard to explain.

Comment: As I described above there is two steps.
And one of step it seems i found here http://razorjack.net/quicksand/demos

Comment: Some of us have reasonable skill in JavaScript and don't necessarily have an iPhone. It's up to YOU to describe the problem and we can help with the solution. What you're asking for is first help describing the problem and then help with the solution. Find a video. Make a video.